# Blank image appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib, itk, medical

I am using simpleITK to process MRI images in .mha format. I subsequently convert it into a numpy array. I am able to visualize the images using matplotlib.However, if I perform any prerprocessing or I multiply the image by its binary mask, all I get is a blank image. Is there something I am missing. My simplified code is shown below.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
input_image = sitk.ReadImage('MRI.mha')
input_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(input_image)
plt.imshow(input_array[0,:,:],cmap = 'gray') # I get an image for this. No preprocessing has been performed.
plt.show()
# However, if I replace input_array after preprocessing, I get a black square.
```

I think this has something to do with the range of the data, but I am not able to pinpoint where. The image visualized before preprocessing has a maximum value of 744. After preprocessing, this drops down to 4, and that is when problems crop up. Any pointers to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Try to check the minimum and the maximum of your data after the preprocessing. Also make sure you are not creating NaNs or any values that would appear masked. This is to make sure the problem is not your data but something in the plot itself. If possible, can you provide a randomized example so that other people can test for themselves?

Comment: The data after preprocessing falls in the range 0 to 4. There are no NaNs in the data. This is the image (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwD-ZZ_dzJIgaF83aTljWUtVLVU) which contains labels, which I use to preprocess the MRI image. This link (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwD-ZZ_dzJIgaWpSREZPRGxFQjg) the MRI image.

Comment: So, the RF classified image has 7 labels. Label 1 is White Matter. Labels 4,5,6 and 7 are the tumour regions.

Comment: What is the pre processing step you are taking? Both images are stored as integers. Maybe casting into floating point will fix your problem - hard to say without knowing what you're doing to the data!

Comment: I first find the average intensity of white matter. Then I divide the entire image by this intensity.

Comment: @g.stevo How to cast the images into floating point?

Comment: sitk.Cast ( image, sitk.sitkFloat32 ) - check your average intensity is not an integer.

What version of Python are you using - check by dividing a single pixel value by this value - what does it return

Comment: The average intensity is 62.5516. I am using Python 2.7. If I divide a single pixel by the average intensity, I get 0.0. I just picked the location randomly. After dividing the entire image by the average white matter intensity, I also ensure that the tumour regions all end up having values between 0 and 1, by subtracting the minimum of the tumour regions from the tumour regions, and then dividing it by the maximum intensity of the tumour regions.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your image pixel type before any processing. The MRI image volume which you are testing on has a sitkInt32 (Signed 32 bit integer) pixel type. So there is a high chance that your processing (e.g. your division operations) would make your pixel values zeros and you get black images.
You can either cast your image to float using SimpleITK:

```
input_image = sitk.ReadImage('MRI.mha')
print(input_image.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())
input_image = sitk.Cast(input_image,sitk.sitkFloat32)
input_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(input_image)
```

or change your numpy array data type before processing:

```
input_image = sitk.ReadImage('MRI.mha')
input_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(input_image)
input_array = input_array.astype(np.float32)
```

Read more about pixel types at [SimpleITK Image Basics notebook](http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/01_Image_Basics.html).